# Missing keyboard language in all UITextField and UITextView

Tags: ios, localization, keyboard, uitextfield

We have an app, deployed to more than milion users.
Some of them report that they don't see chinese or russian keyboard when they try to select a language to type (but they do see other languages).
They say it happens only on our app.
Since I'm not familiar with an API to set what languages the user see in his keyboard, I really don't know what to do here.
The issue is not reproduced on our devices..

Some notes:
1. The language is on the languages list on the user settings. 
2. The users say it happens only on our app.
3. It happens to a small friction of users (not all of them).
4) It's being solved after reinstall the app.

Any direction?

Comment: Wow I’ve got the exact same issue. Russian or Hebrew users normally get back to us saying it’s only happening with our app, and only in some screens. Normally setting the keyboardType can lead to this, but I’m not doing that. It works at first they say and then after a few hours it stops and switches to an English keyboard with the emoji button instead of the language switcher button.

Comment: You can now tell them it happens on other apps as well... :)

Comment: I'm sure you knew that wouldn't work ;) This issue is irritating especially since I cannot reproduce it at all, yet I can see people experiencing it daily.

Comment: I have the same issue, @strangetimes ,  did you set the app language by `UserDefaults.standard.set(["xx"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")`? this is the only code may cause the problems, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Yes I am, but the rest of the app works, it’s only one of several places that seems to exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Has anybody managed to figure this one out?